# If row status is 1 output approved on the view using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I want to output the statement you are APPROVED if table row column status is 1. 
Am able to output data from the database. Now i want to output the statement only.

**My controller**

```
public function index(){

    $this->load->database();  
    $this->load->model('Truckeraccount_model');  
    $data['account_details']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->account_details(); 
    $this->load->view('header'); 
    $this->load->view('truckers/truckeraccount_view', $data);  
    $this->load->view('footer'); 

}
```

**My Model**

```
public function account_details() { 

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('trucker');          
    $query = $this->db->get('trucker');      
    return $query;

}
```

**My View**

```
  <?php
        foreach ($account_details->result() as $row)  
  {
  ?>   
            Area - <?php  echo $row->area;?><br>
            Mobile Number - <?php  echo $row->phone_number;?><br>
            Address - <?php  echo $row->address;?><br>
            Email Address - <?php  echo $row->email_address;?><br>
            Status - <?php  echo $row->status;?><br>

 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Use `if`, it's simple.

Comment: hahahaha..done...thanks man..i feel stupid you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `if` statement like this,

```
<?php
    foreach ($account_details->result() as $row)  
     {
     ?>   
        Area - <?php  echo $row->area;?><br>
        Mobile Number - <?php  echo $row->phone_number;?><br>
        Address - <?php  echo $row->address;?><br>
        Email Address - <?php  echo $row->email_address;?><br>
        Status - <?php  if($row->status == 1) { echo 'you are Approved'; }?><br>

    <?php } ?>
```